# C++ Can a class pass itself by reference?

Tags: c++, reference

Trying to pass a parent class object to a child class object so that the child class object has control over the parent class object's methods.

This is however resulting in header related issues.
I've tried forward declaring one of the classes but it seems whatever class is declared first always has trouble reading from the class declared below.

Both errors refer to Device' constructor where try to call dm's hello world method, they are:

```
Use of undefined type 'DeviceManager'
Left of '->HelloWorld' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
```

...

```
//main.cpp
#include "parent.h"

void main()
{
    cout << "Created DeviceManager\n";
    DeviceManager* deviceManager = 0;
    deviceManager = new DeviceManager;

    cout << "Giving  DeviceManager a device\n";
    deviceManager->p = new Device(deviceManager);

    cout << "Giving  Device a reference to DevicenManager\n";
    deviceManager->Share();
}
```

...

```
class DeviceManager;
class Device
{
public:
    Device(DeviceManager* manager)
    {
              dm = 0;
        this->dm = manager;
        this->dm->HelloWorld();
    }

    DeviceManager* dm;
};

//device manager
class DeviceManager
{
public:
    DeviceManager()
    {
        p = 0;
    }
    void HelloWorld()
    {
        //if this calls we know the child has control over the parent.
        cout << "Hello World";
    }

    Device* p;
};
```

Comment: Pass itself by reference to what? Can you share some code demonstrating your issue? Your question is unclear so far because it feels like as if it questioned the existence of reference.

Comment: Show us the code that gave you trouble. It's perfectly acceptable for an object to pass itself as a reference.

Comment: provided some code so hopefully things make sense now.

Comment: Make sure you know what you're doing here. Not implementing `Device::~Device` will obviously cause a memory leak, and not implementing a copy constructor, or not knowing why you should, will ruin your day. In C++11, you should set `dm` to `nullptr` instead of 0. In earlier versions of C++, you should set it to `NULL`. In C++11, you _probably_ also should use `std::unique_ptr`, which will avoid the above pitfalls.

Comment: Hey, Mic, thanks :) I do use unique_ptr and have deconstructors in the real program and you're right, I've never fully understood why we use copy constructor.

Answer (score 7):

Yes.

To solve circular dependencies with class member and function declarations, you can forward-declare a class:

```
class A;

class B {
        A *a;
};

class A {
        B *b;
};
```

To define class member functions that access members of the other class, you must define the function *after* the other class has been defined:

```
class B;

class A {
public:
        void f(B &arg);
};

class B {
public:
        void g(A &arg);
};

void A::f(B &arg) {
        arg.g(*this);
}

void B::g(A &arg) {
        arg.f(*this);
}
```

Usually, in a `C++` project, you wouldn't even encounter this problem: You would put function definitions, i.e. implementations, into `.cpp` files, while putting the class definitions into header files. Class forward declarations, if neccesary, could be put into their own header files that are included by all headers that need them.

A full example of how you would split the above code into multiple files:

**a.cpp**

```
#include "a.h"

#include "b.h"

void A::f(B &arg) {
    arg.g(*this);
}
```

**b.cpp**

```
#include "b.h"

#include "a.h"

void B::g(A &arg) {
    arg.f(*this);
}
```

**a.h**

```
#ifndef _A_H_
#define _A_H_

#include "forward_declarations.h"

class A {
public:
    void f(B &arg);
};

#endif //_A_H_
```

**b.h**

```
#ifndef _B_H_
#define _B_H_

#include "forward_declarations.h"

class B {
public:
    void g(A &arg);
};

#endif //_B_H_
```

**forward_declarations.h**

```
#ifndef _FORWARD_DECLARATIONS_H_
#define _FORWARD_DECLARATIONS_H_

class A;
class B;

#endif //_FORWARD_DECLARATIONS_H_
```

As a general rule of thumb, if you need to forward-declare a class, you might have misdesigned something and should think about whether there is a better way (but there also are perfectly valid use cases that require class forward declarations).

If you don't understand my `#ifndef`, `#define` and `#endif` preprocessor lines: These are header guards, and **should** be used with **all** files that are included somewhere else, exception you know **precisely** what you're doing. Believe me. You'll regret ommiting one.

Comment: Are you sure that you understand what the OP is trying to ask? It is better to ask for clarification than guessing ... For instance, I cannot understand what circular dependency you are talking about in your example. There is nothing circular in your code at all.

Comment: What OP was most likely talking about when he mentioned that his 'include paths create an infinite loop' are circular header dependencies, which are caused by two class definitions that require the other classes declaration, and can be solved by forward-declaring the classes.

Comment: I do not know what the OP was trying to ask. I will wait for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is cyclic dependancy, like this:

```
// DeviceManager.h
#include "device.h"
class DeviceManager
{
    DeviceManager(Device& device) {}
};

// Device.h
#include "DeviceManager.h"
class Device
{
    Device(DeviceManager& manager) {}
};
```

You can solve the problem be *forward declaring* one of the classes, and passing the object by pointer.

```
// Device.h
//#include "DeviceManager.h"
class DeviceManager;
class Device
{
    Device(DeviceManager* manager) {}
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I believe this will help a lot :)